# How to set value in odata of radiobuttons like inputfield

Tags: radio-button, odata, sapui5

I am creating a form now. In a line I need only answer with yes or no. the Code now looks like this

```js
<Label text="Billable" 
 labelFor="flag"/>
<Input value="{appointments>flag}"
 id="flag"
 placeholder="set a flag in true or false"/>
```

and i need radiobuttons with yes or no. I have tried to write radiobutton, but it does not work

```js
<Label text="Billable" />
<VBox binding="{appointments>flag}">
 <RadioButton  text="true"/>
 <RadioButton  text="false"/>
</VBox>
```

the value property an the RadioButton is not allowed. How can i set the value from radioButton to the {appointments>flag} in ODatamodel like inputfield as above?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not altogether clear to me. When you say "does not work" what did you mean? If you want to bind RadioButton selectio to a model then the property binding is <RadioButton selected="{appointments>flag}"> provided flag is a boolean value. If it is not a boolean value then use a formatter function to return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selectedIndex property if the [RadioButtonGroup](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.RadioButtonGroup.html) to set the Radio Button from the model.

```
<RadioButtonGroup columns="3" width="500px" selectedIndex="{appointments>flag}">
        <buttons>
            <RadioButton  text="true"/>
            <RadioButton  text="false"/>
        </buttons>
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

In your case, selectedIndex  should be either 0 or 1, 0 being true and 1 being false

Comment: hello,thanks, that work, now i must write a controller, if the value 0 then to yes, if value 1 then to no.

Comment: and the other question.  i want set the flag, if 0 then flag value is Yes, if 1 the the flag value is No.  how can i do it?

Comment: You could use two-way binding and it will be set automatically to the model

Answer (score 0):

You should try using data binding the control with the model.

```
<RadioButtonGroup columns="3" width="500px" selectedIndex="{/flag}" buttons="{/buttons}"  select="radioSelectionHandler">
            <buttons>
                <RadioButton  text="{label}"/>
            </buttons>
        </RadioButtonGroup>
```

You controller can be something like this

```
onInit: function() {
    var radioButtons = {
        "buttons":[
                      {
                          "key" : "true",
                          "label" : "True"
                      },
                      {
                          "key" : "false",
                          "label" : "False"
                      }
                  ] ,

    }       

    this.getView().setModel(new  sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(radioButtons));
},

radioSelectionHandler : function(event){
    var flag = this.getView().getModel().oData.flag;
    sap.m.MessageToast.show(this.getView().getModel().oData.buttons[flag].key);
}
```

I added the key property which you use in if else check in controller rather than using the display text.
Hope this helps!